# mysql query bug

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select id, s
from (
         select o_user_id as id, sum(total_price) as s
         from Orders o
         group by o.o_user_id
     ) as t1
where s = (select max(t1.s) from t1)
```

it returns a bug said table t1 doesn't exist.

I want to find the id of the user who spends the most money among all of the orders

here is the table of order
[image]

Answer (score 4):

That alias is out of scope for the subquery

```
select id, s
from (
         select o_user_id as id, sum(total_price) as s
         from Orders o
         group by o.o_user_id
     ) as t1
where s = (select max(t1.s) from t1)
```

You can do

```
WITH T1 AS 
    (
      select o_user_id as id, sum(total_price) as s
         from Orders o
         group by o.o_user_id
     ) 
SELECT id, s
  FROM T1
 WHERE s = (select max(t1.s) from t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select o_user_id as id, sum(total_price) as s
from Orders o
group by o.o_user_id
order by s desc
limit 1;
```

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions.  To get multiple rows in the event of ties, use `rank()`:

```
select ou.*
from (select o_user_id as id, sum(total_price) as s,
             rank() over (order by sum(total_price) desc) as seqnum
      from Orders o
      group by o.o_user_id
     ) ou
where seqnum = 1;
```